# Android Show Notification only when Message arrives

Tags: android, notifications, google-cloud-messaging

In Android, I have implemented Google Cloud Notification, which notifies when any message arrives, but it stays even when message is there, it shows icon in notification bar immediatly after installing application, is there any way to only show the notification when message arrives and hide it once the user clicks on it ??

Here is my code :

```
    private static void generateNotification(Context context, String message) {
    int icon = R.drawable.ic_launcher;
    long when = System.currentTimeMillis();
    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager)
            context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    Notification notification = new Notification(icon, message, when);

    String title = context.getString(R.string.app_name);

    //Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);           //Open Activity
    // set intent so it does not start a new activity

    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);

    notificationIntent.setData(Uri.parse("http://www.google.com"));                  //Open Link

    notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP |
            Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
    PendingIntent intent =
            PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, notificationIntent, 0);
    notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, title, message, intent);
    notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;

    // Play default notification sound
    notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;

    //notification.sound = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + context.getPackageName() + "your_sound_file_name.mp3");

    // Vibrate if vibrate is enabled
    notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE;
    notificationManager.notify(0, notification);      

}
```

Comment: Yes, but without any code from you, it is hard to tell where you are having problems.

Comment: Sorry, Tanis.7x -- Just updated my code

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing where you are receiving messages and where you want to generate and cancel Notifications, it is very difficult to discern what you need to do to implement this, but I will give it a shot.

If you load the sample project for an [Android Connected App Engine project](https://developers.google.com/eclipse/docs/endpoints-androidconnected-gae) (via GCM), you will notice that GCM data is received in a [GCMBaseIntentService](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gcm/GCMBaseIntentService.html).
This class has a method you can override called `onMessage()` that will be called whenever you receive a GCM message. If you create the notification in this method, then your application will only generate a notification when a GCM message is received.

As for cancelling notifications- you can do so by calling the NotificationManager's `cancel()` method, passing the ID of the notification you want to cancel. Presumably you have some sort of Activity that displays messages to the user, and this would be a good place to cancel any outstanding Notifications relating to a specific message.

Comment: That's great help. Thanks Tanis.7x will try the same